# Make a good relation between group, users with an owner with entity framework code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I would try to make a relation between two entities : A goup (with an owner and users) and user (which belongs to a unique group). Code :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public virtual Group group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } 
}
```

I don't arrive with data annotation to make it corectly.

Thank you so much for your propositions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that works for me :

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? GroupId { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Users")]
    public virtual Group group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? OwnerId { get; set; }
    public User Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } 
}
```